# How do I find a document using Mongolab's $oid with pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mlab

I'm trying to do this:

```
event = coll.find_one({"_id": {"$oid": event_id}})
```

Where event_id is the string from an ObjectId:

```
event_id='50bbd48eefbdd2a1e83bc440'
```

but the event ends up empty. I'm certain this is not how you find documents with the ObjectId's in pymongo, but I have searched for a while and have not figured out how. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to convert `event_id` to an `ObjectId` like this:

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
event_id='50bbd48eefbdd2a1e83bc440'
event = coll.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(event_id)})
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert it back? My query returns ObjectId('asdfa') that doesn't match any document _id.

Answer (score 0):

When searching by id with `event_id` the ObjectId string as you define it, simply do

```
event = coll.find_one(event_id)
```